Jackson class not found with Kotlin and Spring Data
I have a class stored using Spring Data:
@Entity
class CorePlayer(
    val uuid: UUID,
    var name: String,
    var firstJoin: Long,
    var lastJoin: Long,
) : BaseEntity()

I am then accessing that class using a JpaRepository with some Redis caching:
@Repository
interface CorePlayerRepository : JpaRepository<CorePlayer, Long> {

    @Cacheable("core_player_uuid", key = "#uuid", unless = "#result == null")
    fun findByUuid(uuid: UUID): CorePlayer?

    @Cacheable("core_player_name", key = "#name", unless = "#result == null")
    fun findFirstByName(name: String): CorePlayer?

    @Caching(
        put = [
            CachePut("core_player_name", key = "#result.name"),
            CachePut("core_player_uuid", key = "#result.uuid")
        ]

    )
    fun save(entity: CorePlayer): CorePlayer

}

When I call this code:
repository.findByUuid(uuid) ?: repository.save(CorePlayer(...))

I get a strange error:
Could not read JSON: Failed to parse type 'uk.m4xy.modules.core.player.CorePlayer' (remaining: ''):
Cannot locate class 'uk.m4xy.modules.core.player.CorePlayer',
problem: uk.m4xy.modules.core.player.CorePlayer 

My CacheManager is setup as follows
   @Bean
    fun cacheManager(connectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory): CacheManager {
        val cacheConfig: RedisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration
            .defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(StringRedisSerializer()))
            .serializeValuesWith(
                RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                    GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer().configure {
                        it.registerModules(KotlinModule.Builder().build())
                    })
            )
            .entryTtl(Duration.ZERO) // Infinite Cache

        return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(cacheConfig)
            .build()
    }


Is this a classpath issue, a jackson-kotlin issue or an oversight. Any advice would be appreciated.

I don't know some of those frameworks, but I suspect a build/classpath issue.  Can you show your build.gradle file (or whatever you're using to build it)?
